# Woocommerce multiple sites one orders database

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a project based on Wordpress and WooCommerce. My goal is to set multiple sites (on different domains with different content) and one orders database with one admin panel (not in Wordpress - custom script). How can I manage WooCommerce to save orders and orders_meta on different database? HyperDB or something else? Question is when I save orders to other DB will table indexes be a problem?